# What is inside of a conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

There are many answers regarding why is the electric field inside a conductor zero. But my question is, how do you define **inside**?

Often times, my book uses 'inside' for the entirety of the volume, and sometimes, *insides means inside the material of conductor, not inside the object necessarily* as in not the insides of a hollow thick sphere but in it's thickness (just an example). Which one of the two is true?

Edit: Between the spheres of a spherical capacitor, is not the electric field non-zero while still being "inside" the conductor?

Comment: Between the plates of a spherical capacitor is not inside a conductor, it's the space between two conductors.

Comment: @Triatticus that's precisely my question. I want clarification on why sometimes the space between two conductors is used and other times, the volume of a conductor is treated as "inside" even if it is empty inside!

Comment: Inside means a point inside the conducting material.  If there’s a hole in your conductor, a point inside the hole is not inside the conducting material.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero so if I have a hollow sphere with some thickness and radii $R_1$ and $R_2$ where $R_1<R_2$, inside would mean inside the thickness (the volume between $R_1$ and $R_2$) and not like inside the empty space from centre to $R_1$ right?

Comment: Yes.  There has to be conducting material at the point under consideration.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero the electric field being zero before $R_1$ (Atleast that my book says, it is zero there) is not a consequence of this then (this= E field inside conductor is zero). Is that right too?

Comment: The electric need not be $0$ in the region $r<R_1$, but it can be $0$ for a thick spherical hollow shell if the hole contains no charge (using Gauss’ law).  Irrespective of the charge in the region $r<R_1$, the field will be $0$ in the region between $R_1$ and $R_2$ if this region is filled with a conductor.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks! So if a charge is kept in $r<R_1$ it will induce an opposite and equal charge at the surface whose locus is $R_1$ so that E field between R1 and R2 is zero and in so doing, develop a charge of equal magnitude and sign in addition to any charge that may have previously been there on the surface. That about concludes it?

Comment: yes.  See this image https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/538909/36194 for the case of a charge not at the center, but your argument about induced charges remains true.  Better yet see this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/356470/36194

Answer (score 3):

A conductor is defined by the property that the electrons are fairly mobile so they are able to redistribute themselves in order to cancel the electric field due to any excess charge. But the electrons are bounded by the surface of the conductor or the work function. So you can still have accumulation of charge on the surface that creates an electric field outside the conductor. So inside can be thought of as the region in which the electrons are mobile.

Answer (score 0):

A common misconception is, that physics has an official precise definition of each and every term that is used. Physics is not mathematics. If you want to understand what you read, you have to read carefully what the respective author writes. Sometimes it is written explicitly, most often it is only written between the lines. Language is imperfect outside mathematics. So what is meant by "inside" and "outside" in the literature you are using, can only be answered by the author of the text, or you as the attentive reader.

Answer (score -1):

Conductors are mostly solids which have free electrons in it which allows conductivity through it. So inside conductor there are atoms which have free electrons. Depending upon the no. Of free electrons we can tell which conductors has more conductivity.